# Can I make a script wait for a key press when it has opened itself in a new terminal window?

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard

I came across this line

```
if [ ! -t 0 ]; then x-terminal-emulator -e "$0"; exit 0; fi
```

which I can write at the top of a script and when clicking on the script file in nautilus, the script will open itself in a terminal window so that I can see the output.

Now there is the problem that this command

```
read -n1 -r -p "Press any key to continue..." key
```

in this case will not wait for a key press.

My guess is that x-terminal-emulator may be the reason, but I haven't found any other solution to double click a script file in Nautilus and get a new terminal window where the script will run.

Comment: Your line is sooooo close:  `read -n 1 -s -r -p "Press any key to continue..."`

Comment: @Terrance I've copied your line into the script but it does not wait.

Comment: If you copy and paste to a cli it works fine.  Are you adding it to a function in your script?

Comment: It's standing in the main part. I've tried just "read key" which seems to work, I guess that is a solution, although I don't know why.

Comment: Is your script starting with `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`?  The read commands are different per shell.

Comment: It did not start with any of these which apparently caused  trouble together with read -n1.

Comment: `-n 1` works fine in every test I have thrown at it as long as it is `bash`.  Next time, please add your script to the question so that we can help assist you better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cannot reproduce. This code

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -t 0 ]; then x-terminal-emulator -e "$0"; exit 0; fi
echo "new window"
read -n1 -r -p "Press any key to continue..." key
echo bye
```

when run with `./foo.sh </dev/null` opens in a new terminal and waits for a key press.

You'll need to be more explicit about your code.

Comment: You're right. Found out I left out #!/bin/bash and used -n1 in the read command, and then it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
read -r -p "Press any key to continue..." key
```

waits for the Return key, no matter if #!/bin/bash has been used or not.

When

```
#!/bin/bash
```

is at the top of the script, -n1 will work and will wait for any key.